# Is it possible to get resource information by ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a list of ARNs for resources in AWS. Is it possible to get information using boto3 given an ARN value? There are many different kinds of resources, so a unified way would be best.

Comment: Any example? Also what kind of information?

Comment: I would like to get creation/modified timestamp for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a service called [Resource Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resource-explorer/latest/userguide/welcome.html). Boto3 provides a way to use this service. Checkout the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resource-explorer-2.html).

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get the date a resource was created? It doesn't look like it, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but it does seem to be possible. Check this out: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config/client/get_resource_config_history.html